# Wrong metadata used when using like or recommend button

Tags: metadata, facebook-like, facebook-recommendations

I searched and searched and did not found answers.

I build a website with a certain name. After that, I created an app on Facebook. I connected my website with this app and everytime someone liked something, the app took metadata from my website. No prob. But I was not satisfied with the domain I used. So I changed the name of my website and then changed the app parameters. After that when people liked or recommended my a page, facebook kept showing the same metadata (description). For 99,99999999% I'm certain that the shown metadata is not on my server or in any map on my website. I believe it's "floating" somewhere on the servers of Facebook. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Linting your url should clear Facebook's cache.  At least that's what their documentation says.